# Redirecting previous domain subfolder links

Tags: php, apache, redirects, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've recently bought a domain that was unregistered. After looking in Google webmaster tools, Google is trying to crawl random pages that don't exist. Turns out it did have a previous owner.

The offending pages are in the style

```
mysite.com/catalog/?Brand=0&Model=102&ID=0
```

Although there doesn't seem to be any links on the web (who knows what the previous owner did) I want these to point to my homepage.

I've tried redirecting using..

```
redirect 301 /catalog/ http://mysite.com/
```

but I end up with a redirect to my homepage with an URL in the address bar of...

```
mysite.com/?Brand=0&Model=102&ID=0
```

How do I get it to just redirect to my homepage and show URL mysite.com in the address bar with no gubbings on the end?

I am on an Apache server with PHP 5

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have actual visitors hitting those URL's (in which case a 301 redirect page _might_ be useful), wouldn't it be better to just respond with a 404? Google will see that those pages don't exist anymore and eventually stop crawling them. Even if visitors _are_ hitting those URL's I'd still recommend using a nice, helpful, informative 404 page over a potentially confusing redirect.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I though Google penalised sites with lots of 404 errors.

Comment: You won't be penalized for responding to a request for a non-existent page with a 404. In fact, that's exactly the point of a 404. Here are a couple useful links: [1](http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/seo-and-404-pages/01022013/), [2](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-bad-links-14660.html)

Comment: Thanks BigBagel, I was under the impression that 404 = bad site design and upkeep. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append a `?` to the end of the domain in the redirect rule to prevent the query string from being append to the final redirected url.

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/.*$ http://www.mydomain.com? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for a quick reply that solved the problem!